# Iterating an Array for overlapping ranges

Tags: java, arrays

I have some results stored in a boolean array of size 10^6.
There are given some queries i.e. indexes (start index and end index) to find total number of true values in given index range in boolean array.
I tried but all could figure out is O(n) solution.

Is there any way to optimize the answer as i can observe overlapping in given queries.

There could be overlapping queries also

**Example**

```
        boolean[] ArrayBool=new boolean[1000000];
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
        {
        //Random True/False assigned to ArrayBool
        }
    while(no. of querires)
    {
i1 (start index)
i2 (end index)

output: Total no. of True in Bool array

    
    }
```

Example input: Given ranges [1,100], [50,1000], [20,50000] etc.

Answer total True values in given range.

Is there any efficient approach to iterate through array other than O(n).

Comment: You can look for the minimum value of start and the maximum value of end. Loop once through your boolean array and test if the value is true and which query it will match. If it is more efficient depends on the ranges in your queries

Comment: See https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/RoaringBitmap